# How we simplify the term $\frac{a^0}{2}+\frac{a^1}{2\cdot4}+\frac{a^2}{2\cdot4\cdot2}+\ldots+\frac{a^{n-1}+a^nx}{2\cdot4\cdot2\cdot4\ldots}$?

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

The following Engel expansion can be simplified:
$\frac{a^0}{2}+\frac{a^1}{2^2}+\frac{a^2}{2^3}+\frac{a^3}{2^4}+\ldots+\frac{a^{n-1}+a^nx}{2^n}=\frac{a^{n-1}(x+1)-2^{n-1}}{a^{n-1}}$

How do we simplyfiy the expansion:

$\frac{a^0}{2}+\frac{a^1}{2\cdot4}+\frac{a^2}{2\cdot4\cdot2}+\frac{a^3}{2\cdot4\cdot2\cdot4}+\ldots+\frac{a^{n-1}+a^nx}{2\cdot4\cdot2\cdot4\cdot2\cdot4\ldots}$

or even

$\frac{a^0}{2}+\frac{a^1}{2\cdot2}+\frac{a^2}{2\cdot2\cdot4}+\frac{a^3}{2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot2}+\ldots+\frac{a^{n-1}+a^nx}{2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot2\cdot2\cdot4\ldots}$

It would be very interesting to generalize such behavior.

Comment: Group the even index terms in one series, the odd... Please use $\cdot$ obtained via `\cdot` instead of that $*$ for a better typographic quality.

Comment: The last series admits of a grouping w.r.t. the ranks $1,4,7,...$ and $2,5,8,...$ and ...

Comment: Thank you very much for that hint. I will try to implement your idea.